# How to set source for only one column

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

I've got a `DataGrid` whose main purpose is to allow the user to enter data in its cells.

However, the first field in this grid should display the contents of a list.

How would I go about setting the data source for just one column?

**EDIT**: I want to achieve something like this:

[image]

Comment: how is the row data from the first column related to the other columns? i mean for every row the first column is different in dependence to the other colums of that row?

Comment: can you add a picture what you wanna achieve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Specify your own `DataGridTemplateColumn` in `DataGrid.Columns`, and set the `DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate` to whatever it is you're looking to place in that column.

For example, if you wanted it to be a `ComboBox` pointing to some other list of fields:

```
<DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Fields">
        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=MyWindow, Path=DataContext.SomeCategoryList}"
                          SelectedItem="{Binding SomePropertyOnDataItemInRow}" />
        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
</DataGrid.Columns>
```

I'm using a property called `SomeCategoryList` that's on `MyWindow.DataContext`, however you can set the binding to point to wherever your field list is stored

Comment: I've tried this code, however it is not letting me add a "DataGridColumn" and saying that i should specify what kind. So I tried a DataGridTemplateColumn, however this does not have an "ItemTemplate" property.

Comment: @DotNET Sorry, I did that without looking up the exact syntax. You'll want a `DataGridTemplateColumn`, and you'll want to set the `CellTemplate` for it. I updated my answer to the correct syntax

Comment: Rather than using a combobox, how could i just substitute a plain text entry?

Comment: Basically just to get the fields column to look like the image i posted in the question

Comment: @DotNET Honestly... I'd just add a string property to whatever object you're binding your `DataGrid.ItemsSource` to. Although I suppose if you don't want that then you'd probably need a converter of some kind to figure out what Row you're in, and return the correct text for that row.

Answer (score 1):

in addition to my comment, one easy way would be to wrap your itemssource collection and add a list for  every item - with the data you expect.

the good thing is you do not have to set a different source for your first column, you just have to bind to the new list property

EDIT:

i hope i got your problem.

lets say you have a itemssource for your grid:

```
List<MyObject> _list;
```

your myobject contains Asc/Desc, GroupBy, Having, Dispplayorder properties.

so i would create a MyObjectWrapper and add the Field property

```
  public class MyObjectWrapper
  {
     public MyObject WrappedOject {get;set;}
     public string Fields {get;set}
  }
```

you end up with a new

```
 List<MyObjectWrapper> _wrapperlist;
```

these collection have all information you need to display.

Comment: I'm not sure i understand. Basically i've got a grid which is to take the user's input from the cells. The first field is just used as a category for each row